# htaccess Open folder only if redirected from another folder

Tags: php, wordpress, .htaccess

i searched here a lot, found similar posts but didn't work for me.

i have a wordpress site, and for security reasons i want to make a new folder in the root folder with name "father". and make it password protected, then after the user enters the password it redirects him to "wp-admin" login. BUT also, any one who didn't go to "father" folder can't get access to "wp-admin" folder AT ALL.

i really don't know how htaccess works, but i know that it has a major role in this.

any help?!

Answer (score 0):

simply put the .htaccess/.htpasswd files into your wp-admin folder.
you can use a htaccess generator like [this one](http://www.webmaster-toolkit.com/htaccess-generator.shtml) if you don't know how to create the files...